# Dynamic TimelinePlot glitching out

Tags: plotting, dynamic

Hi `Dynamic` Noob here :)

I have written the following piece of code:

```
now:=CurrentDate["Minute"];
DynamicModule[{
    intervals={{DateObject[{2022,4,18,5,5},"Minute"],DateObject[{2022,4,18,20,6},"Minute"]},DateObject[{2022,4,19,5,4},"Minute"]},
    timeMarkers=KeyValueMap[Labeled[#2,#1]&,<|"One"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,6,31},"Minute"],"Two"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,13,18},"Minute"],"Three"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,17,4},"Minute"],"Four"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,21,32},"Minute"],"Five"->DateObject[{2022,4,19,1,17},"Minute"]|>],
    plot
},
    EchoLabel["Timeline:"]@Dynamic[
        FinishDynamic[];
        plot=TimelinePlot[{DateInterval/@intervals,timeMarkers,{Labeled[now,"You are here!"]}},Filling->Below];
        Style[plot,DynamicUpdating->True],
        TrackedSymbols->{},
        UpdateInterval->60
    ];
    "some other code with more dynamics"
]
```

But for some reason after updating the first two items in the `TimelinePlot` disappear. How do I fix this? and can someone give me an explanation of the problem as well.

Output before update:

[image]

Output after update:

[image]

Comment: What is the code that triggers an update?

Comment: @JasonB. There is no trigger, see the option `TrackedSymbols->{}`. The update happens periodically with `UpdateInterval->60`, i.e. every one minute which is exactly the granularity being used for the `DateObject`s in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need DynamicModule for this. I may be missing something from your context, but I *think* all you need to do is generate the appropriate Dynamic expression. Ultimately, this is the expression that does the job (I've added a bit so we can see changes and I lowered the update interval so we don't need to wait so long):

```
Dynamic[
  TimelinePlot[
    {DateInterval/@intervals,timeMarkers,{Labeled[now,"You are here! "<>DateString[now]]}},Filling->Below],
  UpdateInterval->1,TrackedSymbols->{now}]
```

Now, if you don't want the dependencies to be global, you can use a With:

```
With[
  {intervals={{DateObject[{2022,4,18,5,5},"Minute"],DateObject[{2022,4,18,20,6},"Minute"]},DateObject[{2022,4,19,5,4},"Minute"]},
  timeMarkers=KeyValueMap[Labeled[#2,#1]&,<|"One"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,6,31},"Minute"],"Two"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,13,18},"Minute"],"Three"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,17,4},"Minute"],"Four"->DateObject[{2022,4,18,21,32},"Minute"],"Five"->DateObject[{2022,4,19,1,17},"Minute"]|>]},
  Dynamic[
    TimelinePlot[
      {DateInterval/@intervals,timeMarkers,{Labeled[now,"You are here! "<>DateString[now]]}},Filling->Below],
    UpdateInterval->1,TrackedSymbols->{now}]]
```